# Batch: Renaming files numeric (Count up every time)

Tags: batch-file, numeric, counting

I hope I didn't confuse anybody with that title, I can't quite describe my problem well in a short line... I have a folder with multiple files (all have the same extension) and I want to rename all of them numeric. It should be easy since the batch file would have to count up every time it replaces a name. But I could be wrong.

I don't know much about batch apart from some basics, but I'm always happy to learn more.

Thanks in advance for any answer!

Comment: Did you try doing this by yourself? If yes, do share it here.

Comment: @S.Ahmad Yes, but I did not get very far. In fact, I managed to write about 5 lines before I noticed that I need to tell the batch to count up and I don't know how to do that and all other solution on the internet seemed way too complicated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It will be simpler to create an empty folder, move the files into the new folder whilst renaming them, and then move them back to the old one. That way, you won't have any possible issues with renaming existing files, or iterating through files you've already renamed.

My original solution:

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set folder=C:\path\to\existing\folder
md %folder%.TEMP
set /a n = 0
for %%f in ("%folder%\*") do (
    set /a n += 1
    move "%%f" "%newfolder%\!n!%%~xf"
)
move "%folder%.TEMP\*" "%folder%"
rd %folder%.TEMP
```

Updated with @Compo's comments, numbering the files with leading zeros in order of time created (change /TC to /TW to use last modification date instead):

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set folder=C:\path\to\existing\folder
md %folder%.TEMP
set /a n = 0
for /f "delims=" %%f in ('dir/b/a-d-s-l/od/tc "%folder%"') do (
    set /a n += 1
    set zn=0000000!n!
    set zn=!zn:~-8!
    move "%%f" "%newfolder%\!zn!%%~xf"
)
move "%folder%.TEMP\*" "%folder%"
rd %folder%.TEMP
```

Comment: I would suggest padding with zeroes ordered by dates and times such that they can still be sorted. _Will moving the files alter original timestamps?_

Comment: @Compo - padding added.

Comment: I still think that your numbering should be based around the existing written, `\TW`, or created, `\TC` time stamps. `For /F "Delims=" %%f In ('Dir/B/A-D-S-L/OD/TC "%folder%"') Do (`

Comment: @Compo thanks for the clarification; I added your suggestion.